# how do i take a dictionary out file i save in a csv file and store it as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

This is in my csv file:

```
{'Name': 'The Hero', 'Min Damage': 2, 'Max Damage': 4, 'Defence': 1, 'HP': 20, 'Inventory': [], 'fought': False, 'Y': 1, 'X': 0}
```

This is what I tried to bring the dictionary out

```
def resumegame():
    filename = 'C:/test/savegame.csv'
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return {}
    with open(filename) as ifh:
        return dict(line.split() for line in ifh)
```

Comment: It would help if you specified which programming language you are using. Do you want to import the contents of a CSV file to a dictionary? If yes, I would recommend you to change the post title and add that information to the post contents, it will help people find your question and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [yaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) module

```
import yaml

def resumegame():
    filename = 'C:/test/savegame.csv'
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return {}
    with open(filename) as ifh:
        return yaml.load(ifh)
```

Comment: i tried it and it works thanks so much for the help

Comment: can i also use json to take the file out instead of using yaml

Comment: I didn't understood what you are asking? do you want to write the output to json file?